# Go to Line keyboard shortcut in Python editor IDLE?

Tags: python

In the Python editor IDLE I can do "Edit > Go to Line", but when I try cmd+j (alt+g on Windows), then IDLE freezes. How can I go to line in IDLE on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLE > Preferences (cmd+,) > Keys > goto-line > Get New Keys for Selection